# how is it possible to display continuously calculated values of functions from a class?

Tags: python, multithreading

I want the program to run continuously and output the values from the methods (func1 - func4) as soon as a signal gradient is detected on the pins.

This is just a test code to understand how I can access the values, because I have written a "program" with a surface that shows uninterrupted values from a machine where I use ONLY global variables and I don't want to post that here because it's embarrassing...
and i want to get rid of all the global variables

A raspberry pi is connected to the machine with which I intercept 4 signals over the gpio.

```
cavity = 2
count = 0
scrap = 0
uptime = datetime.timedelta(0)
downtime = datetime.timedelta(0)

def func1(channel):
    if GPIO.input(7) == 0:
        while True:
            uptime = uptime + datetime.timedelta(0,1)
            time.sleep(1)
            if GPIO.input(7) == 1 or GPIO.input(37) == 0:
                break

def func2(channel):
    scrap = scrap + cavity

def func3(channel):
    count = count + cavity

def func4(channel):
    if GPIO.input(37) == 0:
        while True:
            downtime = downtime + datetime.timedelta(0,1)
            if GPIO.inpu(37) == 1:
                break

GPIO.add_event_detect(7, GPIO.RISING, callback = func1, bouncetime = 100)           #Run
GPIO.add_event_detect(29, GPIO.RISING, callback = func2, bouncetime = 100)          #Scrap
GPIO.add_event_detect(13, GPIO.RISING, callback = func3, bouncetime = 100)          #Count
GPIO.add_event_detect(37, GPIO.RISING, callback = func4, bouncetime = 100)          #Alarm

class Output(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.show()

    def show(self):
        print('ich werde aufgerufen')
        while True:
            print(uptime)
            print(scrap)
            print(count)
            print(downtime)
            print('############################')
            time.sleep(5)


thread2 = Output()
thread2.start()
```

only zeros are output this was to be expected but how do i get access to the variables so that on signal detection the values increase

Comment: Each of your functions needs to declare the variable they are writing to as `global`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code written as two classes:

```
class Events:
    def __init__(self):
        GPIO.add_event_detect(7, GPIO.RISING, callback = self.func1, bouncetime = 100)           #Run
        GPIO.add_event_detect(29, GPIO.RISING, callback = self.func2, bouncetime = 100)          #Scrap
        GPIO.add_event_detect(13, GPIO.RISING, callback = self.func3, bouncetime = 100)          #Count
        GPIO.add_event_detect(37, GPIO.RISING, callback = self.func4, bouncetime = 100)          #Alarm

        self.cavity = 2
        self.count = 0
        self.scrap = 0
        self.uptime = datetime.timedelta(0)
        self.downtime = datetime.timedelta(0)

    def func1(self, channel):
        if GPIO.input(7) == 0:
            while True:
                self.uptime = self.uptime + datetime.timedelta(0,1)
                time.sleep(1)
                if GPIO.input(7) == 1 or GPIO.input(37) == 0:
                    break

    def func2(self, channel):
        self.scrap = self.scrap + cavity

    def func3(self, channel):
        self.count = self.count + cavity

    def func4(self, channel):
        if GPIO.input(37) == 0:
            while True:
                self.downtime = self.downtime + datetime.timedelta(0,1)
                if GPIO.inpu(37) == 1:
                    break


class Output(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, events):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.events = events
        self.show()

    def show(self):
        print('ich werde aufgerufen')
        while True:
            print(self.events.uptime)
            print(self.events.scrap)
            print(self.events.count)
            print(self.events.downtime)
            print('############################')
            time.sleep(5)


events = Events()
thread2 = Output(events)
thread2.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your functions are just creating their own local variables, so the global ones don't change.

Try this:

```
def func1(channel):
    global uptime
    if GPIO.input(7) == 0:
        while True:
            uptime = uptime + datetime.timedelta(0,1)
            time.sleep(1)
            if GPIO.input(7) == 1 or GPIO.input(37) == 0:
                break

def func2(channel):
    global scrap 
    scrap = scrap + cavity

def func3(channel):
    global count
    count = count + cavity

def func4(channel):
    global downtime 
    if GPIO.input(37) == 0:
        while True:
            downtime = downtime + datetime.timedelta(0,1)
            if GPIO.inpu(37) == 1:
                break
```

Comment: there is no other way ? i have often read global variables one should not use. I knew that I can solve this with global but can I also solve it differently?

Comment: Yes, make another class which combines all the stuff above `class Output`.

Comment: Can you send me an example?